# Generating PDB for existing binary file from known source

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-debugging, pdb-files

I have got a binary file that crashes, and corresponding dump file. I also have sources that are used to build that binary, but I am not the one who compiled it.

Is it somehow possible to build a `pdb` file to be used to inspect problems recorded in dump, especially since timestamp and sources location are different from machine that was used to compile binary file? Iam using Visual Studio 2015 if that is of any relevance, project is statically linked with Boost and some other libraries.

Comment: I just recompile the sources when I face this problem.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe if I recompile the source, obtained crash data will be useless as well. The point is exactly to find out if it is possible to recreate pdb with access to code. Although it is likely to be impossible.

Comment: Excellent question. I also faced this question once in the past, and I didn't find a good answer. It seems to me that any minor changes in the settings of the compiler will generate incompatible PDBs. I wonder if anyone has the answer...

Comment: @AdiLevin it seems also, that a timestamp affects binary trace used to distinguish compatible `pdb`s. But I am not sure if this is used in case of C++ builds.

Comment: @sukhmel: why will it be useless? Assuming you know the right compiler flags, of course. I have no problem with this approach as long as I use WinDBG (and not Visual Studio) with the .symopt+0x40 option.

Comment: I think you might be able to get some useful information without a PDB. Do you have a stack trace with addresses, and an indication of the .dll for each address?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff558827.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#symopt_load_anything

Comment: @AdiLevin no, there is no info besides pdb. VioletGiraffe, that's a good idea, if I can use pdb generated with same compiler flags with WinDBG then I should give it a try later.

Comment: @HansPassant: Adding an instruction how to use that in Visual Studio 20xx will make a beautiful answer!

Comment: @krlmlr I am also stumbled upon this problem, it seems like there should be an option, but that's pretty obscure.